# Do I need to capture billing address information?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

In the example for accepting payments by credit card ([link](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/accept-credit-cards/)) the billing address information is not present. However, the payment appears to go through. What are the circumstances that require me to include this data?

Answer (score 0):

In the classic API, the address fields are required. I can't find a field reference for REST, oddly enough. I suppose you could omit them and try a sandbox call to see if it fails, but omitting the address means no address verification (done against the zip code). It opens you up some to fraud.